# Exception: a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' that could not be found

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Am getting below error in connecting hibernate entity manager with my sql and application start up failing . Springboot version 2.0.5.RELEASE

> Description:
>
> Parameter 1 of method imdbEntityManager in **** required a bean of
>   type 'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder'
>   that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder' in your
>   configuration.

I have gone through multiple answer in stackoverflow nothing helpful for now.

Config.java

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "com.******.imdbsearch.repository" }, 
entityManagerFactoryRef = "imdbEntityManagerFactory", 
transactionManagerRef = "imdbTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ImdbConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource")
    public DataSource imdbDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name="***EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean imdbEntityManager(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder){
        Map<String, Object> objMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();     
        objMap.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect");
        objMap.put("hibernate.show_sql", true); 
        objMap.put("hibernate.default_schema","imdb");
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource)
                .properties(objMap)
                .packages("com.*****.imdbsearch.entities")
                .persistenceUnit("target")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "imdbTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("imdbEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "imdbJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate slaveJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
```

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class })
public class ImdbSearchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ImdbSearchApplication.class, args);
    }
```

yml file

```
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*****
    username: *******
    password: ********
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    generate-ddl: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
        ddl-auto: validate
```

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.*****</groupId>
    <artifactId>imdb-search</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>imdb-search</name>
    <description>Searche in IMDB </description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <lucene.version>6.6.0</lucene.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId> <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId> 
            <version>${lucene.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId> 
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId> <version>${lucene.version}</version> 
            </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId> <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId> 
            <version>${lucene.version}</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version> -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please post your pom.xml (or Gradle file)

Comment: added pom @eugen

Comment: Having the same issue now, but it's working fine in another project. Trying to find the differences... Hopefully will have an answer shortly.

Comment: OK, in my case I had a multi-datasource configuration, and the problem went away when I annotated one of the datasources as `@Primary` (which makes no sense at all). But your config seems to be a single-datasource one, plus you do have the `@Primary` annotation.